# What's the equivalent of `heroku container:release web` without using heroku-cli?

Tags: continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a bitbucket pipeline that almost working:

```
image: atlassian/default-image:2

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        services:
          - docker
        script:      
          #Build the image    
          - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME ./backend
          #Login to heroku's docker registry with an API token
          - docker login --username=_ --password $HEROKU_TOKEN registry.heroku.com

          #Tag and push our built image to the heroku docker registry
          - docker tag $IMAGE_NAME registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APPLICATION_NAME/web
          - docker push registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APPLICATION_NAME/web
```

The final step is - I would run something like `heroku container:release web  -a=$HEROKU_APPLICATION_NAME`

How can I do that without actually having the heroku-cli (ie. from the bitbucket pipeline).

Answer (score 1):

You can install the Heroku CLI via `npm` - which might be the simplest.

Note that your Heroku API key has to have the env var name `HEROKU_API_KEY` for the Heroku CLI to accept it as an auth token (ie. to avoid having to do `heroku login`).

```
          - npm install -g heroku

          # build the Docker image (this will use the Dockerfile in the root of the repo)
          - docker build -t $HEROKU_APPLICATION_NAME ./backend
          # authenticate with the Docker Hub registry
          - docker login --username=_ --password $HEROKU_API_KEY registry.heroku.com

          - docker tag $HEROKU_APPLICATION_NAME registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APPLICATION_NAME/web
          - docker push registry.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APPLICATION_NAME/web
          - heroku container:release web -a=$HEROKU_APPLICATION_NAME
```